# PHP Mailer Fails To Connect To Server

Tags: php, gmail, phpmailer

here is my php code:

```
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer(); 
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->CharSet="UTF-8";
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = 'clubbedinapp@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'pw';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->From = 'clubbedinapp@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Clubbed In';
$mail->AddAddress('nishil.shah17@gmail.com');
$mail->AddReplyTo('clubbedinapp@gmail.com', 'Information');

$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via Sendmail, basic";
$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";
$mail->Body    = "Hello";

if(!$mail->Send())
{
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

I followed a Gmail PHPMailer tutorial, I have no idea what is wrong? Can someone please help?

Comment: You followed an obsolete tutorial. Base your code on [this example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps), and [read these docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you enable openssl on your php.ini?

Go to PHP.ini and find a line called

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

and remove the semi colon in the beginning of the line.

Stop the Apache server and all servers, start them again, 
and try it again.

Comment: hi, how do I access the php.ini? Where would that be located?

Comment: It will be located in your PHP installation directory.